# How to detect if span is created in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

This is actually related with ASP.NET MVC.

When a form is submitted, model validation is performed. If an error is detected, the error message will display in a `<span>`. We should be able to get hold of it using `jQuery`, by `$('span.field-validation-error')`. But what event should we bind to for this "OnCreated"?

I have tried `$('span.field-validation-error').change(function (e) {`, `$('span.field-validation-error').load(function (e) {` etc. But none of them worked.

So what is the correct event name?

----Update----

Our goal is to customize the error message displayed. If it is possible to edit that `<span>` tags when they are created, we will be able to display an exclamation mark icon and place those error messages in the tooltip, for example.

Comment: What's your goal? Depending on what you want to do with these `<span>`s, there might be a different angle from which we could attack the problem.

Comment: @Blazemonger: I think with client-side validation in MVC, those fields are already created when the page is rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **GUESS** you could:

```
var checkTimer = setInterval(function() {
        if ($('span.field-validation-error').length > 0) {
            //yay :D it exists!
            alert("YEP");
            clearInterval(checkTimer);
        } else {
            //derp...    
            console.log("nope");
        }
}, 50);
setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = "<span class='field-validation-error'>word</span>";
}, 5000);​
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/Ynz5b/1/

**[edit]** Yes... it's messy, I hate timers and intervals - but this is one way to do it...
**[edit 2]** Reference for checking if elements exist: http://aaronrussell.co.uk/legacy/check-if-an-element-exists-using-jquery/

Comment: Thank you for the posting and continuous update. It appears to be the best and only solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what you really want to do is wrap up some code in another function and call that at the same time that `span.field-validation-error` is appended to the DOM.

There is no `onCreated` event handler nor will `onLoad` work for DOM nodes.

Comment: What a disappointing answer! I will wait for some more replies to destroy my hope.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'd actually recommend this approach for what you are doing, but you could consider hooking into the jQuery validator settings.showErrors property to manipulate the error messages and then call the default method (defaultShowErrors) afterwards to display them as usual.